# Until + tense / "since" or "for"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, tenses

Is any of these sentences correct?

> 1. Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played to this game for 5 years.
> 2. Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played to this game since 5 years.
> 3. Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played this game for 5 years.
> 4. Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played this game since 5 years.

And can I just say, "until 2 months ago" instead of "until I played again 2 months ago"?

Comment: Can you clarify if the "to" in the first two examples is a typo or part of the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

> Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played this game for 5 years.

*Playing to* something is what you do with a talent to something else, normally a person or group of people, for example:

> I played [my guitar] to the audience

Doing something *since* something works for events or milestones, e.g:

> I haven't played this game since I broke my arm.
>
> I've been living here since I was five years old.

And yes you can say

> Until 2 months ago, I had not played this game for 5 years.

Comment: I would say "I played [my guitar] *for* the audience" (without the emphasis).

Answer (score 1):

> Until I played again 2 months ago, I had not played this game for 5 years

is correct.  So too is

> Until 2 months ago, I had not played this game for 5 years